# たら followed by question mark

Tags: translation

Situation. A person is a bit unstable and is basically talking/monologuing besides someone who isn't conscious as if they were. She wonders about something and when the unconscious person doesn't visibly respond, that we can see she says this:

> ねぇ
>
> なにか言ったら？

First Ne is I assume her again prompting the unconscious person for comments.

The second bit is kinda problematic. Without that question mark it would be "when (you) say something" but I'm not sure how to take this with that question mark. Could this basically be "When will you say anything?"?

Answer (score 0):

> なにか言ったら？

This is a suggestion and translates to something along the lines of `Say something...?` / `How about you say something...?`.

Comment: What does this answer add to the fully detailed answer that I linked to above?